# better way to fill dropdown list in mvc

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, drop-down-menu, html-select

I have tried to create dropdown list with  tag

```
        <select name="manufacturer" class="form-control">
            <option>@null</option>
            @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <option>@item.Manufacturer</option>
            }
        </select><br>
```

but here is a problem: It doesn't populate all available `manufacturers` and only shows items, from current page. Example: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0eMr7.png

that's because it uses the model passed from controller which doesn't always contain every item from the database. (because of pagination or after search)

Here is full sidebar code in `partial view`

```
 @model IPagedList<Products>
@using PagedList
@using PagedList.Mvc

<div id="filter" class="left">
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Filter", "SearchFilter")) {
        <div>
            <b>Manufacturer:</b> <br>
            <select name="manufacturer" class="form-control">
                <option>@null</option>
                @foreach (var item in Model) {
                    <option>@item.Manufacturer</option>
                }
            </select><br>

            <b>Name:</b> <br>@Html.TextBox("name", null)<br>
            <b>Price From:</b> <br>@Html.TextBox("min", null)<br>
            <b>To:</b> <br>@Html.TextBox("max", null)<br>
            <button type="submit" value="search"><b>Search</b></button>
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

So what are the ways to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know why it's occurring

> that's because it uses the model passed from controller which doesn't always contain every item from the database. (because of pagination or after search)

then why not fix it right there. Maybe you need a separate validation table for manufacturers (if you don't already have one).

Model:

```
public class ProductsModel
{
    public IPagedList<Products> CurrentProducts {get; set;}
    public int ManufacturerId {get; set;}
    public int MinPrice{get; set;}
    public int MaxPrice{get; set;}
}
```

Controller action:

```
[HttpGet]
public ViewResult CurrentProducts()
{
    ProductsModel model = new ProductsModel();
    model.CurrentProducts = _repository.Product;
    ViewBag.ManufacturerId = from p in _repository.Product select p.Manufacturer;
    return View(model);
}

[HttpPost]
public ViewResult CurrentProducts(ProductsModel model)
{
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        model.CurrentProducts = _repository.Product.Where(t=>t.ManufacturerId == model.ManufacturerId);
        ViewBag.ManufacturerId = from p in _repository.Product select p.Manufacturer;
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

And in the view, create a dropdown list like this:

```
@model MyNameSpace.ProductsModel
@Html.DropDownListFor(model=> model.ManufacturerId, string.Empty);
```

Comment: thanks for the response. I thought about what you suggested before I posted the question,  but is there any way to do it without creating separate table for `manufacturers` because I don't have one.

Comment: You can save the `ViewBag.Manufacturer_Id` before doing the pagination logic

Comment: well, that almost helped. I tried this way
`ViewBag.Manufacturers = from p in _repository.Product
                                    select p.Manufacturer;`
and in view inserted it in `foreach` cycle. But got `RuntimeBinderException`saying `'string' does not contain a definition for 'Manufacturer'`

Suggestions?

Comment: can you paste your for loop here?

Comment: Sure. here it is `@foreach (var item in ViewBag.Manufacturers) {
        <option>@item.Manufacturer</option>
    }`

Comment: your `@item` is a `string`, and strings don't have a property called `Manufacturer` like the exception is suggesting. Just do `@item` in `<option>`

Comment: no prob; check my edit, if possible encapsulate your model instead of spitting out a naked list